# Github pages: is there a way to publicly store an api key... without publicly storing an api key

Tags: github, github-pages

alrighty so this is a really stupid question, I know, but I was wondering if there was ANY possible way I could store an api key to my JSON cloud storage (Pantry) in a static html site (and the JS in the client needs to upload data to it), and how websites normally go about it (if it is at all possible without serverside processing) and seeing how I am using github pages I don't have access to serverside processing (sorry if I did something wrong in this post, I'm very new to stack overflow, and English is second language)

Not really much, a couple searches which lead to gitignore but I still need the javascript to interact with Pantry, and upload a username and password along with miscellaneous user data to the storage- I am poor so hosting my own website is a challenge financially.

Comment: One possibility: store it in your browser's local storage so it isn't placed online, but is still accessible to your application.

Comment: no there is not. either provide an input to store it in localstorage, or better: if oauth is supported, implement the implicit flow and then store the token in localstorage